# Dealing with durations defined by days, hours, minutes and seconds such as "1d 3h 2m 28s" in R

Tags: regex, r, time

I have a data frame with character vectors in the format with days, hours, minutes and seconds represented like "1d 3h 2m 28s":

```
> head(status[5])
    Duration 
1 0d 20h 46m 31s 
2  2d  0h 13m 54s
3  2d  0h 13m 53s
4  0d  9h 53m 38s
5  5d 12h 17m 37s
6  0d 10h 21m 19s
```

I can  parse it with regex for the components but cannot come up with a good way to convert the duration into seconds. I can `gsub` the vectors into an expression that would result in the number of seconds but hit a road block with using `eval` on the results.

I could do something similar to what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389428/dealing-with-time-periods-such-as-5-minutes-and-30-seconds-in-r) but hoped to follow the regex route - even if it isn't the most efficient. I'm only dealing with parsing a variety of small HTML tables.

```
status$duration <- gsub("(\\d+)d\\s+(\\d+)h\\s+(\\d+)m\\s+(\\d+)s.*","\\1*86400+\\2*3600+\\3*60+\\4",as.character(status[,5]),perl=TRUE)
```

The above creates an expression that can be evaluated but I'm missing something when it comes to `parse(text=status$duration)` and a subsequent `eval`.

In perl, I'm accustomed to taking the "captured variables" in the regex expression and immediately using them rather than only within a replacement string. Are there similar possibilities in R?

Thank you, I'm probably missing something very simple due to fogginess of mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and last solutions below seem the simplest but the ones with complex regexps correspond more closely to what might have been done in perl.

Before listing the solutions themselves, note that in them we assume the input is `tt` and the conversion vector `mult` is a 4-vector whose components are the number of seconds in a day, hour, minute and second.  We can set `mult` as in the comment or calculate it as shown:

```
tt <- c("0d 20h 46m 31s", "2d 0h 13m 54s", "2d 0h 13m 53s", 
   "0d 9h 53m 38s", "5d 12h 17m 37s", "0d 10h 21m 19s")
# mult <- c(86400, 3600, 60, 1)
mult <- rev(cumprod(rev(c(24, 60, 60, 1))))
```

Here are 4 approaches:

**1) strapply extracting numerics** We can use `strapply` in the gsubfn package to avoid complex regular expressions.  `strapply` is used to extract all the numbers arranging them in a matrix and multiply by `mult` stringing out the result in a plain numeric vector:

```
library(gsubfn)
mat <- strapply(tt, "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
secs <- c(mult %*% mat)
```

The two lines could be combined into a single statement but we will leave it as above in case you wish to examine `mat` separately.

**2) strapply with complex regexp** Another possibility, also using `strapply` is the following single statement.  The captured strings are placed into the free variables as they are encountered so the first capture goes into `day`, the second into `hour`, etc.   This one may be closer to what you would have done in perl:

```
secs <- strapply(tt, "(\\d+)d (\\d+)h (\\d+)m (\\d+)s", 
 ~ 86400 * as.numeric(day) + 3600 * as.numeric(hour) + 
    60 * as.numeric(minute) + as.numeric(second), simplify = TRUE)
```

**3) strapply with complex regexp but vectorized** or even shorter:

```
secs <- strapply(tt, "(\\d+)d (\\d+)h (\\d+)m (\\d+)s", 
  ~ as.numeric(list(...)) %*% mult, simplify = TRUE)
```

**4) strsplit** and here is another single statement answer. This one does not use `strapply` but makes use of the fact that a matching separator at the end of the string is just removed without the following empty string output.  See `?strsplit` for details.

```
secs <- sapply(strsplit(tt, "[dhms]"), function(x) as.numeric(x) %*% mult)
```

The result from any of the above is:

```
> secs
[1]  74791 173634 173633  35618 476257  37279
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the first question I've posted and I've learned quite a lot from each of the answers.

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. The problem is that the `eval` function is not vectorised.  This means you need to wrap each element of your results string into an `apply` statement to evaluate each element in turn.

First recreate your data:

```
status <- c("0d 20h 46m 31s", "2d 0h 13m 54s", "2d 0h 13m 53s", 
       "0d 9h 53m 38s", "5d 12h 17m 37s", "0d 10h 21m 19s")

duration <- gsub("(\\d+)d\\s+(\\d+)h\\s+(\\d+)m\\s+(\\d+)s.*","\\1*86400+\\2*3600+\\3*60+\\4",
                 as.character(status),perl=TRUE)
[1] "0*86400+20*3600+46*60+31" "2*86400+0*3600+13*60+54"  "2*86400+0*3600+13*60+53" 
[4] "0*86400+9*3600+53*60+38"  "5*86400+12*3600+17*60+37" "0*86400+10*3600+21*60+19"
```

---

To evaluate a single element:

```
eval(parse(text=duration[1]))
[1] 74791
```

---

Wrap this in `sapply` or your favourite `apply` statement to evaluate all of the strings:

```
sapply(duration, function(x)eval(parse(text=x)))

0*86400+20*3600+46*60+31  2*86400+0*3600+13*60+54 
                   74791                   173634 
 2*86400+0*3600+13*60+53  0*86400+9*3600+53*60+38 
                  173633                    35618 
5*86400+12*3600+17*60+37 0*86400+10*3600+21*60+19 
                  476257                    37279
```

Comment: Not sure why you need `textConnection`? `parse(text=x)` works fine, where x is a character string. So `sapply(duration, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))` should do the trick.

Comment: @HongOoi Thank you. I knew there had to be an easier way. I have edited my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to R and aggressively trying to grok the power of it. Thank you for the reminder and example with `sapply`.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by splitting the strings by space using `strsplit`.

```
a <- c("0d 20h 46m 31s", "2d 0h 13m 54s", "2d 0h 13m 53s", 
       "0d 9h 53m 38s", "5d 12h 17m 37s", "0d 10h 21m 19s")

a.values <- sapply(a, strsplit, " ")
```

Now, `a.values` will be:

```
> a.values
$`0d 20h 46m 31s`
[1] "0d"  "20h" "46m" "31s"

$`2d 0h 13m 54s`
[1] "2d"  "0h"  "13m" "54s"

[cut]
```

Now, we write a little function that takes a 4 elements vector like those and converts it to seconds. Essentially what I do is removing the letter at the end of each element, convert it to a number and multiplying it for an opportune value (86400=24*60*60 for days, 3600=60*60 for hours and so on).

```
convert.to.sec <- function(timestamp)
    {
    # Remove the last character (d, h, m, s) from each element    
    values <- sapply(timestamp, function(x){as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1))})

    mult <- c(86400, 3600, 60, 1)
    res <- sum(mult * values)
    }
```

Now we can do

```
sapply(a.values, convert.to.sec)
```

et voilà!

```
0d 20h 46m 31s  2d 0h 13m 54s  2d 0h 13m 53s  0d 9h 53m 38s 5d 12h 17m 37s 
     74791         173634         173633          35618         476257 
0d 10h 21m 19s 
     37279
```

Comment: You could also remove the characters with your `strsplit`: `strsplit(a,"[a-z][ ]*")`

Comment: I like the simple elegance of the function. Certainly a solution to consider and @James, I didn't realize the regex strength within strsplit.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `*apply` loops by getting `strsplit` produce your output and then `unlist`ing converting to a `matrix`, weighting and using `colSums`:

```
a <- c("0d 20h 46m 31s", "2d 0h 13m 54s", "2d 0h 13m 53s",
     "0d 9h 53m 38s", "5d 12h 17m 37s", "0d 10h 21m 19s")

mat <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(a,"[a-z][ ]*"))),nrow=4) #transposed by default, rows represent time units, cols cases

colSums(mat*c(86400,3600,60,1))
[1]  74791 173634 173633  35618 476257  37279
```