# How to convert char string like "70 min" , "1 hr 30 min" and N/A to a numeric type in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I have a column which has value of runtime as "70 min" or "1 hr 30 Min" and N/A etc. I want to convert these values to numeric, like 70 min should be 70 and 1 hr 30 minutes should be 90. Also, I want to Keep N/A as it is.

```
a<- c("70 min", "1 hr 30 Min")
typeof(a)

a <- as.numeric(a)
```

when I tried as.numeric, it converted everything to NA, some experiments with lubridate package also disappointed me. Any expert advice please.

Comment: Your options are either to use a package which can handle such a string, or to do it yourself.

Comment: Here's an older answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802903/dealing-with-durations-defined-by-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds-such-as-1d-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicate link did not look particularly appetizing to me, so I will offer the following regex based solution.  Assuming your non standard timestamp be in a fixed and known format, we can use a regex to extract out the various portions.  Under the assumption that you only have hour and minute information, you can try:

```
a <- c("70 min", "1 hr 30 Min", "Blah")
hrs <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?(\\d+) [Hh]rs?.*", "\\1", a))
hrs[is.na(hrs)] <- 0
min <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?(\\d+) [Mm]in.*", "\\1", a))
min[is.na(min)] <- 0

total <- hrs*60 + min
```

**Output:**

```
> min
[1]  0 30  0
> hrs
[1] 0 1 0
> total
[1]  0 90  0
```

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, my data has three formats, first is like 1 h 30 min, second is like 40 min and third is N/A.

Comment: But your solution is returning Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion and it converted everything to NA_real_

Comment: Use `is.na()` to replace NA values with zero.  Ideally, each of your non standard timestamps would follow its own single format.

Comment: Time <- c("70 min", "1 h 30 min")

Change_in_mimnutes <- function(hms_char) {
  
  # split string
  v <- strsplit(hms_char, " ")[[1]]
  # get numbers
  idx <- seq(1, by = 2, length = length(v)/2)
  nums <- as.list(v[idx])
  # get units and use them as names
  names(nums) <- v[-idx]
  # apply functions, sum and convert to days
  duration <- do.call(period, nums)
  minutes <- period_to_seconds(duration)/60
  return(minutes)
}

sapply(Time, Change_in_mimnutes)

Comment: @RavindraKumar I have updated my answer to handle the NA problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim :)